# How do I set the owner of a message queue?

Tags: c#, msmq

The System.Messaging.MessageQueue class does not provide a way to set ownership of queue.  How do I programmatically set the owner of a MSMQ message queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is to p/invoke a call to the windows api function [`MQSetQueueSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms705190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
void SetOwner(MessageQueue queue, byte[] sid, bool ownerDefaulted = false)
{
    var securityDescriptor = new Win32.SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR();
    if (!Win32.InitializeSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptor, Win32.SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    if (!Win32.SetSecurityDescriptorOwner(securityDescriptor, sid, ownerDefaulted))
        throw new Win32Exception();

    if (Win32.MQSetQueueSecurity(queue.FormatName, Win32.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, securityDescriptor))
        throw new Win32Exception();
}
```

A complete class which defines a `SetOwner` extension method on `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` can be found on [github](https://github.com/gavacho/System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SetOwner)